# Blank ASPX page rendered

Tags: asp.net, webforms

My web application has one page default.aspx that renders a blank html.

I have some CSS and Javascript files included into the page, but in the browser if I see view source then it shows only:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

Sometimes it works...but most of the time it doesn't. Refresh doesn't help either.

Whereas there are plenty of Link references and JavaScript references, none of them are included into the page. I tried to put a debug pointer (and also logging from the page load) but it never gets a hit.

IIS - web dev server does not make any difference. I don't even think its a OS, IIS related issue. because the same code on another project working perfectly on the same machine.

By the way my JavaScript file has some un-usual characters in a string like:

```
    Quote: '»',
    DOT_ESCAPE : '_DOT_',
    NL_ESCAPE: "↕"
```

Is it a problem or not? I have no idea even what's going on. Can anybody suggest something?

Comment: Show some of your asp code.  This is not sufficient info.

Comment: True - we need to see your aspx code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. The problem was the js file has wrong code page.